# How to Auto Hide a QWidget in QT5?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I have integrated Qt5.0.1 with Visual Studio 2010.

I have few things in my Qwidget, which is embed into my parent QWidget.

I want my child Widget to auto hide in a interval of about 10 to 20 seconds.

I can able to use the

QWidget::setvisible(true) and QWidget::setvisible(false) by explicitly calling from any where,
but i want to auto hide my child QWidget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtimer.html).

```
QWidget *w = new QWidget(this);
QTimer *t = new QTimer(this);
connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), w, SLOT(hide()));
t->start(10000);
```

Comment: thanks for your kind response, i will check it and revert back to you.

Comment: Also, more concisely, `QTimer::singleShot(10000, widget, SLOT(hide()));`